# Stop Powershell v2 invoke-command -ComputerName it always runing as V1

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have a Win2003 running Powershell v2. If I run

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$Host.Version}
```

then I get "Version 2.0". However, if I run

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$Host.Version} -ComputerName localhost
```

then I get "Version 1.0"

I assume it's something to do with remote powershell but I've been unable to find the setting. Can anyone help?

NB.

```
WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\InitializationParameters

ParamName            ParamValue
---------            ----------
PSVersion            2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remoting host was first introduced in v2, so remoting host's version is 1 (ServerRemoteHost). When you run `Invoke-Command` without `-ComputerName` you are running command in powershell.exe directly. Try to check (and compare) $Host.Name in both commands, you should see the difference.

PowerShell version is best checked with `$PSVersionTable` - in v1 it's absent, in any newer version it will tell you what version of **PowerShell** you are currently running.

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense. I tried executing PS2 only cmdlets and they worked so I gathered something was missing. Now for the next problem is getting it to use .net 4 rather than 2. But now you've stated ServerRemoteHost then I'll go looking for that to supply a config. Thanks.